# When is dynamic_cast<void*> useful?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, void-pointers, dynamic-cast

5.2.7/7 says something along the lines of:

> If `T` is "pointer to `cv void`", the result is a pointer to the most derived class pointed to by `x`.

What is a good application of this syntax? When should `dynamic_cast<void*>` be used?

Comment: Here's an example of what MSalters is describing: http://ideone.com/84U5ax

Comment: I think allocators can make use of this (memory management). E.g. if you need the starting address of a block of memory, but you only have a pointer to a base class.

Comment: @dyp: If you already have an object, its memory must already be allocated, so an allocator can't allocate that again. And for deallocation you need more than just the base address, you need the most derived type so you can run all destructors.

Comment: @MSalters If your destructor is virtual you don't need the most derived type, and if it isn't virtual it's your own fault and you are screwed anyway.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One common reason is to figure out whether two interfaces `IA*` and `IB*` are in fact pointers to the same underlying object. If you need that, use the cast.

IIRC, it's even possible in case of Multiple Inheritance with a repeated non-virtual base to have two `IA*` pointers which compare unequal, yet point to the same object - because they point to two different `IA` subobjects.

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between `dynamic_cast<void*>(ptr)` and `static_cast<void*>(ptr)` (since `void*` does not have any RTTI or vtable)....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `ptr` is a pointer to class type, so it can have RTTI.

Comment: So what, `void*` is a generic pointer so don't have any RTTI, IMHO.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That prevents the cast _back_ to the original type. And to address your first comment, a `static_cast<void*>` may give you a pointer to a base class somewhere in the middle of the full object, which may not be unique.

Answer (score 6):

When you have something like:

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
bool operator==(const X* px, const Y* py) {
     return dynamic_cast<void*>(px) == dynamic_cast<void*>(py);
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a superfluous `return` here?

Comment: And you are casting away `const`.